# when can I know if a class (complexity) is closed under reduction (cook/karp)

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties

How do I know if a class let's say PP , is closed under cook reduction or not closed?

I understand the concept of reduction (how to use it mainly) , but still can't figure out the meaning behind it, as to determine if some problem belong to that class if there is a reduction.

Comment: 1. One question per question, please.  I've edited the question to remove your second question.  You can post it separately, but first do a significant amount of research and/or self-study to see if it is answered in standard resources or elsewhere here, and show us in the new question what research you've done.

Comment: 2. What research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research and/or self-study before asking, and to show us in the question where you've looked and what you've tried.  Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class#Closure_properties_of_classes?  At [tag:closure-properties]?  There's lots already written about the subject on this site; please search before asking.  See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: "I understand the concept of reduction[...] , but still can't figure out the meaning behind it" -- these two statements are contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

There's a clear definition of what it means for a complexity class to be closed under some kind of reductions: a class is closed if, whenever $Y$ is in the class and $X$ reduces to $Y$, then $X$ is also in the class.  To know if a class is closed under some kind of reduction, you need to establish whether or not the class and the kind of reductions satisfy that definition.  To establish this, you need to come up with a mathematical proof. Coming up with mathematical proofs is a creative act which can't be performed according to some fixed recipe.

In general, you should expect that a class is probably closed under some kind of reductions if the class allows computations that are at least as powerful as the reductions. So, for example, you should expect **EXP** to be closed under polynomial-time reductions but expect **P** to *not* be closed under exponential-time reductions. And you'd be correct in both cases.